# combining options in find command from a letter to another

Tags: linux, debian, find, command

Find all the files in `/etc` that have `.config` and starts with letter `a` to the files that starts with letter `k`, that's means all the files from a to `k` in /etc .config.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  What have you tried?  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: maybe `echo /etc/[a-k]*.conflig*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those filenames would match the filename globbing pattern `[a-k]*.config` ("starts with any of the letters `a` through to `k`, and ends with the filename suffix `.config`").

If you're only interested in files located in `/etc`, then the following command would list these files:

```
printf '%s\n' /etc/[a-k]*.config
```

That command would also list directories and symbolic links (etc.) that matched the pattern. To restrict the list to only *regular* files (and symbolic links to regular files), then use a loop:

```
for pathname in /etc/[a-k]*.config; do
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue
    printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
done
```

If you are interested in looking into subdirectories of `/etc` and to restrict the search to only include regular files, then use `find`:

```
find /etc -type f -name '[a-k]*.config'
```

This would look in and below `/etc` for regular files (`-type f`) that has filenames matching the given pattern.

---

The result of the commands above would be a newline-delimited list of pathnames of files.  This list should probably not be used as an intermediate list of pathnames if you're planning on doing further processing of the files.  Instead, use the loop above to process the files individually, or use `find` with its `-exec` option to process them.  This is because the delimiter used in the output, newline, is also a valid character in Unix filenames (granted, you very rarely see it in use, but none the less).

Comment: You may want to set the locale to C for that `[a-k]` to match on `[abcdefghijk]` only. Especially true with  `bash` where `[a-k]` also matches on `[ABCDEFGHIJ]` or `[BCDEFGHIJK]` in most locales at least on GNU systems. Or use `[abcdefghijk]`

Comment: `[ -f filename ]` also matches on symlinks to regular files. Just use `zsh` and `/etc/[a-k]*.config(.)` that has none of those issues (the `[a-k]` range is based on codepoint tere, `(.)` is for regular file only, use `(-.)` for regular file after symlink resolution.